# OpenSea API returning null when i want to fetch my data

Tags: api, ethereum, solidity, nft, opensea

when i go to this link

https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?asset_contract_address=0x892848074ddea461a15f337250da3ce55580ca85

It returns me some data i can use. But when i tried to fetch **MY assets** its not return any data from this link.

https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=0xA48Db0a225703b25ef95B863C1aa44929bBA7FDe

You can see my assets from this link
https://opensea.io/M1croNFT

**How can i fetch my assets data with opensea api?**

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your problem is that to use the `api/v1/assets` method. For this request you need to use the api key. This is written in the description of the method in the [documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/getting-assets).

> **GET** api/v1/assets
>
> Please Note: This API endpoint requires an API key to use. Please fill
> out the API request form to obtain one. [Request an API key](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/request-an-api-key)

So, I think that if you get the key, you will be able to fulfill any request

Another option is to use queries in the test network - [OPENSEA TESTNETS API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/rinkeby-api-overview). I tried to run a [query](https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=0xa48db0a225703b25ef95b863c1aa44929bba7fde&order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=20) there and got the correct response.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to get the Twitter and Instagram (user names) from OpenSea user profile, can you guide me to the correct endpoint? Thank you